# REST API authentication for a plugin

Tags: rest-api, authentication

For a plugin I write a bookmarklet which will make a REST call to an custom post type (CPT) endpoint to save the data.

To save a CPT I need to authenticate the user, unfortunately, this is not implemented in core (yet?). (I'm not talking about Cookie authentication here)

I know I can install this plugin [JWT Authentication for WP REST API](https://wordpress.org/plugins/jwt-authentication-for-wp-rest-api/) and it will work. But I don't want the user to install a second plugin to make it work. Also the JWT plugin needs some configuration setting a secret in wp-config.php.

My question is: What would be the best way to provide authentication within my plugin? Should I implement JWT Authentication for WP REST API myself and check if it is already installed, if not use my version? I'm looking for an easy to use solution for the user.